# Language condition and editing index.php

Tags: joomla-3.x, templates, language

I am trying to edit my index.php for languages and just trying to put my logo on right.

Could you please show me what am I doing wrong?

> I want to put my logo on the left when language is arabic aa-AA and
>   logo on the right when language is english en-GB

Thanks,

```
<?php
  $lang = JFactory::getLanguage();
  $result = $lang->getTag();
  if ($result=="en-GB") { 

       <div id="jf-logo">

        <a href="index.php"><img src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/images/logo.png" alt="JF Texturia"/></a>

      </div>

      <!-- Main menu module -->

      <div id="jf-mainmenu">

        <?php if($this->countModules('mainmenu')) : ?>



           <jdoc:include type="modules" name="mainmenu" />



        <?php endif; ?>

        <div id="jf-submenu"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="submenu" /></div>

      </div>
  } 
  else { 
       <!-- Main menu module -->

      <div id="jf-mainmenu">

        <?php if($this->countModules('mainmenu')) : ?>



           <jdoc:include type="modules" name="mainmenu" />



        <?php endif; ?>

        <div id="jf-submenu"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="submenu" /></div>

      </div>

       <div id="jf-logo">

        <a href="index.php"><img src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/images/logo.png" alt="JF Texturia"/></a>

      </div>
  }
?>
```

Comment: Please clarify. You want to pull your logo to the right when language is "en-GB ? Please update you question, because it is not clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: sorry, i want to put my logo on the left when language is arabic aa-AA and logo on the right when language is english en-GB.

Answer (score 1):

I am probably misunderstanding something here...

You can simply make a module position, two logo modules (custom HTML, really) with a language specified and let Joomla! handle it.

Or you can do it in the CSS using the html[lang="aa-AA"] selector. See [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors). Browser compatibility is good enough I think. (ie anyone using a browser too old for this has bigger problems with your Joomla site...)

Answer (score 0):

Ville Niemi gave you the best answer here.

I think your main problem is that you are mixing up HTML and PHP code. Your file should rather look like:

```
<?php
  $lang = JFactory::getLanguage();
  $result = $lang->getTag();
  if ($result=="en-GB") { ?>

       <div id="jf-logo">

        <a href="index.php"><img src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/images/logo.png" alt="JF Texturia"/></a>

      </div>

      <!-- Main menu module -->

      <div id="jf-mainmenu">

        <?php if($this->countModules('mainmenu')) : ?>



           <jdoc:include type="modules" name="mainmenu" />



        <?php endif; ?>

        <div id="jf-submenu"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="submenu" /></div>

      </div>
  <?php
  } 
  else { ?>
       <!-- Main menu module -->

      <div id="jf-mainmenu">

        <?php if($this->countModules('mainmenu')) : ?>



           <jdoc:include type="modules" name="mainmenu" />



        <?php endif; ?>

        <div id="jf-submenu"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="submenu" /></div>

      </div>

       <div id="jf-logo">

        <a href="index.php"><img src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/images/logo.png" alt="JF Texturia"/></a>

      </div>
<?php
  }
?>
```